# How to hide the file name(filename.jsp) in the URL?

Tags: jsp

I am able to hide the first page of my `JSP` `URL`.I want to know how to mask the next pages file name in `URL`.

For the First page(`abc.jsp`)to second page(`xyz.jsp`) I used the `Web.xml`. I have a form in the Second page which when submitted goes to the Third page(`efg.jsp`).When I submit the Third page, in the URL I can see the file name(`localhost/myapp/efg.jsp`).I don't want it to display the file name. Require Guidance

Thanks in Adv!

P.s:I am using only JSP's.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myapp/xyz.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you hit the URL localhost/myapp/ , it will automatically call your jsp in the back-ground and the URL will remain the same (without the page name i.e xyz.jsp).

Comment: you need to mention in web.xml.

Comment: yeah I did that!!!after the `<welcome-file list>` closing I added the code u said..

Comment: It should work. Please provide your code over here. So, I can check in details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/xyz.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myapp</url-pattern> <!-- Use this URL -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @Vishnu , add this entry in web.xml, how are you invoking the second jsp ? If it is through form submit, you have to change the action as `/myapp/myapp`

Comment: I am directing to the second form using <form action="xyz.jsp"> after submitting!

Comment: It worked but I don't want it to display `/myapp/myapp` also in URL